# How to reduce padding between the icon and text in a xamarin button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have created a button in my xamarin application and have added an icon to it but there is too much of padding between the icon and the text as shown in the screenshot below.

How can I reduce this space between the two?

I have learnt about the custom renders for Xamarin.Android but its not working for me.

Following is the code of my custom renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(ZeroPaddingRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    class ZeroPaddingRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.SetPadding(0, Control.PaddingTop, 0, Control.PaddingBottom);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is your code?@Abhi

Comment: There are a couple of properties you can use if you are using Xamarin.Forms.Views like `Margin`, `Padding`, and `Spacing`

Comment: "I have learnt about the custom renders for Xamarin.Android but its not working for me." This post does not display at all what you have learned. You should share the code of what you have tried

Comment: @AkashAmin I have added the code in my question

Comment: @Dbl please find the code that I have tried in the question above